# Group By Condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a series of documents (check events) in MongoDB that look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5397a78ab87523acb46f56"),
    "inspector_id" : ObjectId("5397997a02b8751dc5a5e8b1"),
    "status" : 'defect',
    "utc_timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-11T00:49:14.109Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5397a78ab87523acb46f57"),
    "inspector_id" : ObjectId("5397997a02b8751dc5a5e8b2"),
    "status" : 'ok',
    "utc_timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-11T00:49:14.109Z")
}
```

I need to get a result set that looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "date" : "2014-06-11",
    "defect_rate" : '.92' 
  },  
  {
    "date" : "2014-06-11",
    "defect_rate" : '.84' 
  }, 
]
```

In other words, I need to get the average defect rate per day. Is this possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The aggregation framework is what you want:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$utc_timestamp" },
            "month": { "$month": "$utc_timestamp" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$utc_timestamp" },
        },
        "defects": {
            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$status", "defect" ] },
                1,
                0
            ]}
        },
        "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "defect_rate": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$defects", 0 ] },
                0,
                { "$divide": [ "$defects", "$totalCount" ] }
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

So first you group on the day using the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) and get the totalCount of items on the given day. The use of the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator here determines whether the "status" is actually a defect or not and the result is a conditional [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) where only the "defect" values are counted.

Once those are grouped per day you simply [**`$divide`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) the result, with another check with [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to make sure you are not dividing by zero.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Makes sense, but it doesn't run in MongoDB console. No error message, I'm trying to wade through and see if it's a syntax thing...

Comment: Are you just copying and pasting? "collection" needs to be the name of your collection. It's just a basic name I use unless you actually specify a query you have tried in your question.

Comment: Yea, I got that changed in my query.

Comment: @user3689902 Missing square bracket. Updated

Comment: If I want to run this query for a particular `inspector_id` (say `ObjectId("5397997a02b8751dc5a5e8b1")`), do I just add that as another condition?

Comment: @user3689902 Pretty much so. There are various aggregation samples in the MongoDB documentation and here on stack overflow as well. If you still have trouble, you can post another question which I am sure someone will answer.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the $match operator might do the trick: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: Is it possible to change the `_id` field so it takes the form `month/day` or `5/11`?

Answer (score 4):

Would this be the best approach for the updated question?

```
$group : {
                _id        : '$symbol',
                amount     : {
                    $sum : '$amount'
                },
                value      : {
                    $sum : '$value'
                },
                occurences : {
                    $sum : 1
                },
                in         : {
                    $sum : {
                        $cond : [
                            {
                                $eq : [
                                    '$direction',
                                    'IN'
                                ]
                            },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                out        : {
                    $sum : {
                        $cond : [
                            {
                                $eq : [
                                    '$direction',
                                    'OUT'
                                ]
                            },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
```