# Arrange $group results into one with specific condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Before asking this question I've read the following posts on SO:

- [grouping by multiple fields and formatting the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269444/grouping-by-multiple-fields-and-formatting-the-result)
- [mongodb group by multiple fields, return newest document with all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71118128/mongodb-group-by-multiple-fields-return-newest-document-with-all-fields)
- [MongoDB query with conditional group by statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191069/mongodb-query-with-conditional-group-by-statement)
- [Group By Condition in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153476/group-by-condition-in-mongodb)

But could not figure out the solution.

I have this data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("63ad7cea911abe16a7e75df3"),
        "number": "1726218093",
        "status_id": ObjectId("922a3bda863a4445182aeb33")
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("a12f7cea911abe16a7e71e3a"),
        "number": "17182180342",
        "status_id": ObjectId("bda863a4445182aeb33922a3")
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("63adb3a7cea911abe16a7e75"),
        "number": "1735218032",
        "status_id": ObjectId("63a4445182aeb3da83922a3b")
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("ea911abe16a7e75df363ad7c"),
        "number": "1722218087",
        "status_id": ObjectId("182aeb3392263a4445a3bda8")
        ...
    }
    ...
]
```

I want to group my data by status and summarize it with specific conditions that depend on status. Here is the expected result:

```
[
    {
        "IN_AUCTION": 6546,
        "PROCESSING": 569,
        "DELIVERING": 124,
        "OTHERS": 68798
    }
]
```

*Conditions:*

"IN_AUCTION" includes these statuses: `["63a4445182aeb3da83922a3b", "ea911abe16a7e75df363ad7c"]`

"PROCESSING" includes these statuses: `["8e63a4445182aeb3da83922a", "5c63adea911abe16a7e75df3"]`

"OTHERS" includes all the remaining statuses

First I grouped them:

```
{
  _id: "$status_id",
  count: {$count: {}}
}
```

After that, I tried another `$group`. But did not come near to the expected result.

Then I tried with `$addFields`:

```
{
  "in_auction": {
    $cond: [
      {
        "$in": ["$_id", [ObjectId('63a432fc82aeb33922a3b8a0'),ObjectId('63a442c782aeb33922a3bd44')]]
      },
      0,
      {$add: "$count"}
    ]
  }
}
```

`$addFields` seems to work on the document itself.

I also read about `$ROOT`, but could not put it in use.

How can I get my desired result? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set `status field` with `$switch` operator to assign value accordingly.
2. `$group` - Group by `status` and perform count.
3. `$group` - Group all documents into one. And adding the document with `k` and `v` properties in the `data` array.
4. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the output document by converting the `data` array into key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      status: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "$status_id",
                  [
                    ObjectId("63a4445182aeb3da83922a3b"),
                    ObjectId("ea911abe16a7e75df363ad7c")
                  ]
                ]
              },
              then: "IN_AUCTION"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "$status_id",
                  [
                    ObjectId("8e63a4445182aeb3da83922a"),
                    ObjectId("5c63adea911abe16a7e75df3")
                  ]
                ]
              },
              then: "PROCESSING"
            }
          ],
          default: "OTHERS"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$status",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EibV_hjSxAQ)

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks @YongShun

Comment: You're welcome. You may also read this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iQpeLI7cDJB) too, this works with `$facet`. But a bit tricky as for OTHERS, you should provide the status_id which shouldn't be the id that used in "PROCESSING", "IN_AUCTION".